# ReferenceField in EmbeddedDocument to master Document

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have `Document` with `EmbeddedDocument` like this in `mongoengine`.
how can create `ReferenceField` in `EmbeddedDocument` for Master `Document` ... master `Document` means that embed my `EmbeddedDocument`

```
class Activity(EmbeddedDocument):
    user = ReferenceField(Profile)
    followed_user = ReferenceField(Profile)
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)


class Profile(Document):
    username = StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    password = StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    email = StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    activities = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Activity))
```

Python said:

```
 NameError: name 'Profile' is not defined
```

Comment: you don't need to add the Reference field in Activity when you are adding the EmbeddedDocumentField in Profiles

Comment: @Crazyshezy why? refrence field create for another user ... for example i follow X and Y and X follow N this say to me X follow N

Comment: Ok got it.. also mongoengine has an `emailField()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

must use `self` in EmbeddedDocuments too

```
class Activity(EmbeddedDocument):
    user = ReferenceField('Profile')
    user_unrelated = ReferenceField('Profile')
    created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

**EmbeddedDocuments** should be used as fields on Documents through the **EmbeddedDocumentField** field type.

Hence your Profile class should be like

```
class Profile(Document):
    username = StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    password = StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    email = StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    activities = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Activity))
```

Note: I am creating a list because there will be more than one activity per profile